# Select count from mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a table containing fields as id user name .... attachresume.

**My query:**

to count the number of resume attached by distinct user, i have tried sub query but am not getting the required output

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Comment: `select count(1) from(select distinct user from table)x`

Comment: @asprin output is perfect what if i want the output as :distinct_user and no_of_resumes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Query :

```
SELECT distinct user, COUNT(attachresume) FROM table_name GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT ID,UserName,Count(attachresume) AS [No Of Resume]
From Table1
Group By ID,UserName
```